# Por que essa bolinha verde consegue retroceder, na animação, usando essa condicional?

Tags: javascript, canvas, animação

Eu tenho um código em javascript que faz uma animação de uma bolinha verde que se movimenta até chegar no limite da largura da janela, fazendo com que a bolinha volte, faça o caminho contrário, até chegar no outro lado da janela, e então voltar de novo e assim por diante.

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

var x = 200;
var dx = 10;
var radius = 30;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x, 200, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    c.strokeStyle = "red";
    c.fillStyle = "green";
    c.stroke();
    c.fill();
    if (x + radius > window.innerWidth || x - radius < 0 ) {
        dx = -dx;
    }
    x += dx;
};

animate();
```

A minha dúvida está nessa condicional:

```
if (x + radius > window.innerWidth || x - radius < 0 ) {
    dx = -dx;
}
```

Na primeira vez que a bolinha chega no limite da janela, a primeira condicional é usada, fazendo com que o valor da várivel `dx` ficasse negativo, para que a bolinha começasse a andar para trás. Agora quando a bolinha chega ao outro limite da janela, a segunda condicional é usada, executando aquele código para deixar o `dx` negativo.
A minha dúvida é, por que, quando a segunda condicional é usada, a bolinha consegue voltar novamente, sendo que o valor da váriavel `dx` já está negativo, não era para continuar indo sem parar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O valor do resultado `dx = -dx;` vai ser *positivo* quando `dx` for negativo.

Por que?

Assumindo que `dx` seja um número negativo `-10`, a expressão seria:

```
dx = -(-10);
```

Sendo assim, pela regra da matemática, `-` com `-` resulta em número positivo, logo:

```
dx = -10;
dx = -dx;
dx = -(-10);

dx = 10;
```

Por outro lado, quando `dx` for positivo, aí `dx` se torna negativo:

```
dx = 10;
dx = -dx;
dx = -(10);

dx = -10;
```

Então, a cada *loop* na função, o `dx` vai trocar de sinal, e uma das condições no `if` será atendida porque irá influenciar no valor do `x`.